# Pipe Output to Python File

Tags: python

How do a make a python script take input that has been piped to it. Is that a `sys.argv` moment. To be clear I want to figure out how to code the python side to receive input like this:

```
cat someFile | domeSomething.py
```

Can this be done? Again, to clarify, I'm not wanting to write this as passing a filename to my script and then using `open(filename)` I want to get piped input. Thanks for the help.

Comment: btw, `cat somefile | foo` should be spelled `foo < somefile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get piped input, you need to read from `stdin`:

```
import sys
print sys.stdin.read()
```

`stdin` is a file, so feel free to use any of the [methods of a file object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Comment: You should add a python hashbang, too: #!/usr/bin/env python